# findByIdAndUpdate is not working with GridFs Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am trying to add one metadata to file object in Grid fs in mongo. But it is not updating (actually I am adding new property called page) metadata in Gridfs.

Following is my code which after saving of document, it tries to update that file with additional property.

```
fs.createReadStream(file)
          .pipe(bucket.openUploadStream(documentId.toString()))
          .on('finish', async (savedFile: File) => {
            let page = 1;

            const letssee = await FilesModel(
              projectContext,
              bucketName,
            ).findById(savedFile._id); // findById is working.

            await FilesModel(
              projectContext,
              bucketName,
            ).findByIdAndUpdate(savedFile._id, { $set: { page } }); // findByIdAndUpdate is not working.

          });
```

What wrong am I doing here? Or simply Grid Fs object doesn't support metadata update?

Comment: try using `{ $set: {page: page}}`

Comment: It was that before. not working :(

Comment: maybe try adding `.exec()` after an query (like `await Model.find().exec()`), btw what is your model? because normally models are not callable like that (`Model(param1)`)

Comment: What is the return value from `.findByIdAndUpdate`?

Comment: @hasezoey yes. that was the issue. exec() with await worked. thank you. please add an answer so that I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments, the solution was:

try adding `.exec()` after the `findByIdAndUpdate` query

used like `await Model.find().exec()`